# Get indices in maximum sum of non-consecutive elements of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I came up with a DP algorithm to compute the maximum sum of non-consecutive elements of an array. I understand there are similar questions but none of them record the indices of the elements which make up the maximum sum.

Original algorithm:

```
def maxSum(arr) {
    sum = [0]*len(arr);
    sum_indices = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i==0:
            sum[0] = arr[0];
        else if(i==1) {
            sum[1] = max(sum[0],arr[1]);
        else
            sum[i] = max(sum[i-2]+arr[i],sum[i-1]);
            
    return sum[len(arr)-1];
```

Attempt at modification to return indices:

```
def maxSum(A):
    n = len(A)
    M = [0]*len(A)
    M[0] = A[0]
    I = [None]*len(A)
    if A[0] > A[1]:
        M[1] = A[0]
        I[0] = True
        I[1] = False
    else:
        M[1] = A[1]
        I[0] = False
        I[1] = True
    
    for i in range(2, len(A)):
        if M[i-1] > M[i-2] + A[i]:
            M[i] = M[i-1]
            I[i] = False
        else:
            M[i] = M[i-2] + A[i]
            I[i] = True
            I[i-1] = False
            I[i-2] = True
    indices = []
    print(I)
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if I[j] == True:
            indices.append(j)
    return indices
```

For example, maxSum([1,2,3,8,9]) should return [1,3,9], but it returns [1, 2, 3, 9].

I have been trying to modify the DP algorithm to return the indices of the non-consecutive elements, but I have been struggling to do so. Is there some trick I'm missing?

Comment: You have a small failing example, a good opportunity to improve your debugging skills. The Example is so small you should be able to do it even with pen and paper.

Comment: Your assumption about the boolean indices is incorrect, lets say your array's elements are bigger from the sum of all other elements before them, do you see that you need to alternate between the whole booleans indices? so it would be [true,false,true,false...true] and the next element would flip all of them to take the new last element which means it would be [false,true,false,true...true] so anyway you need to update the whole array every time which isn't efficient, I would think on other  solution

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that `arr` has only nonnegative elements, then the following should work.

```
def max_sum(arr):
    sum_and_ind= []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        best = (arr[i], -1)
        if 1 < i:
            best = max(best, (sum_and_ind[i-2][0] + arr[i], i-2))
        if 2 < i:
            best = max(best, (sum_and_ind[i-3][0] + arr[i], i-3))
        sum_and_ind.append(best)

    if 0 == len(sum_and_ind):
        return []
    elif 1 == len(sum_and_ind):
        return [0]
    else:
        best_i = None
        if sum_and_ind[-1] > sum_and_ind[-2]:
            best_i = len(sum_and_ind) - 1
        else:
            best_i = len(sum_and_ind) - 2
        answer = []
        while -1 < best_i:
            answer.append(arr[best_i])
            best_i = sum_and_ind[best_i][1]
        return list(reversed(answer))

print(max_sum([1,2,3,8,9]))
```